# WP7 Exception error - Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, onedrive

How do I solve the exception, Operation not permitted on IsolatedFileStream?

After debugging, I realised that a certain line wasn't read and it was skipped to the catch part. I am reading images from the photo samples in windows phone 7 as well as uploading them into skydrive. Can anybody guide me on how to solve this problem asap?
Thanks.

```
public BitmapImage fileName { get; set; }

private void GetImages()
{
    MediaLibrary mediaLibrary = new MediaLibrary();
    var pictures = mediaLibrary.Pictures;

    foreach (var picture in pictures)
    {
        BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
        image.SetSource(picture.GetImage());              

        MediaImage mediaImage = new MediaImage();
        mediaImage.fileName = image;
        UploadFile(mediaImage, picture.Name);                
    }
}

public void UploadFile(MediaImage image, string filepath)
{
   if (skyDriveFolderID != string.Empty) 
   {
     this.client.UploadCompleted += new EventHandler<LiveOperationCompletedEventArgs>(ISFile_UploadCompleted);
     infoTextBlock.Text = "Uploading backup...";
     dateTextBlock.Text = "";

     try
     {
        using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
           // error occurs HERE
           IsolatedStorageFileStream readStream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

           readStream.Close();
           this.client.UploadAsync(skyDriveFolderID, filepath, true, readStream, null)
        }
     }
```

Comment: Could you post the exception data please? A stack trace and the inner exception data would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure error occurs there? I can se you are closing the stream before reading it. So it may be that you got the line of error wrong.

Also, are you absolutely sure, that file with that exact name exists in Isolated Storage?

Comment: The files are inside the isolated storage, however, whenever I run my program, the readStream always read it as null. Hence there's an exception -  Operation not permitted on IsolatedFileStream. I was wonderng how do I solve this? Thanks.